# Error while executing function cannot set property 'width'

Tags: javascript

I call the `function` in this `div`:

```
<div id="sideNavigation" class="sidenav">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Caixa de entrada</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#s1" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv" style="font-size: 70%">Todas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s2" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv1" style="font-size: 70%">Geral</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s3" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv2" style="font-size: 70%">Ocorrências</a></li>
    </ul>
  <a href="#">Mensagens</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#s4" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv3" style="font-size: 70%">Enviadas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s5" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv4" style="font-size: 70%">Não lidas</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
<nav class="topnav">
  <a href="#" onclick="openNav()">
    <svg width="30" height="30" id="icoOpen">
        <path d="M0,5 30,5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
        <path d="M0,14 30,14" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
        <path d="M0,23 30,23" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5"/>
    </svg>
  </a>
</nav>

<div id="main">
<!-- Add all your websites page content here  -->
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.topnav a').click(function(){
  $('#sideNavigation').style.width = "20%";
  $("#main").style.marginLeft = "20%";
});

$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  $('#sideNavigation').style.width = "0";
  $("#main").style.marginLeft = "0";
});
```

When I run on the page and open or close the div, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'width' of undefined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.

Comment: Where is the `main` id?

Comment: @Nicolae Maties I forgot to attach the question, but I already edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what do you want to do but it's better like :

HTML :

```
<div id="sideNavigation" class="sidenav">
<a href="#" class="closebtn">&times;</a>
<a href="#" class="topnav">open</a>
  <a href="#">Caixa de entrada</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#s1" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv" style="font-size: 70%">Todas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s2" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv1" style="font-size: 70%">Geral</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s3" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv2" style="font-size: 70%">Ocorrências</a></li>
    </ul>
  <a href="#">Mensagens</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#s4" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv3" style="font-size: 70%">Enviadas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#s5" class="btn-show" data-element="#minhaDiv4" style="font-size: 70%">Não lidas</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$('.topnav').click(function(){
  $('#sideNavigation').css("width", "20%");
  $("#main").css("margin-left", "20%");
});

$('.closebtn').click(function(){
  $('#sideNavigation').css("width", "0");
  $("#main").css("margin-left", "0");
});
```

do not mix jquery and js

Comment: Creating a responsive slider menu